# Tracking orders efficiently using a Python class

Tags: python, performance, object-oriented, python-3.x

I've written a `Ledger` class for a daemon process, which is supposed to keep track of an exchange's orderbook. My main concern is the way I keep track of the orders -  more precisely, the containers I use to store them: a combination of `set()` and `dict()` appeared like the most feasible solution.
However, I'm wondering If haven't missed a sweet feature or nifty recipe that works better.

But first, my code - the lines in question are within the constructor:

---

```
import logging
from heapq import nlargest, nsmallest

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class OrderRemovalError(Exception):
    pass

class Ledger:
    def __init__(self):
        self._ask_orders = {}  # Keeps orders by price {price: (amount, count)}
        self._ask_ladder = set()  # keeps ask prices
        self._bid_orders = {}  # Keeps orders by price {price: (amount, count)}
        self._bid_ladder = set()  # keeps bid prices

    def _add(self, order, ledger_orders, ledger_oders_ladder):
        price, count, amount = order
        price_key = str(price)
        ledger_orders[price_key] = [amount, count]
        ledger_oders_ladder.add(price)
        return True

    def _remove(self, order, ledger_orders, ledger_order_ladder):
        price, amount, count = order
        price_key = str(price)
        err = []
        c = 0
        try:
            ledger_orders.pop(price_key)
        except KeyError:
            c += 1
        except Exception as e:
            err.append(e)

        try:
            ledger_order_ladder.remove(price)
        except ValueError:
            c += 1
        except Exception as e:
            err.append(e)

        if c == 2:
            pass  # order didn't exist.
            return False
        elif c == 1 or len(err) > 1:
            raise OrderRemovalError("Something went wrong during deletion "
                                    "of order %s! Error: %s" % ((*order,), err))
        elif c == 0:
            log.debug("Order deleted successfully! %s" % (order,))
            return True
        else:
            log.error("Ledger._remove() Error Dump: "
                      "{order: %s, ledger_orders: %s, ledger_order_ladder: %s",
                      ((*order,), ledger_orders, ledger_order_ladder))
            raise ValueError("Passed order caused unforeseen result during "
                             "removal! Inputs have been logged.")

    def bids(self, n=None):
        """
        Returns n bids, returning best first; default returns all.
        """
        if n is None:
            bids = []
            keys = [str(k) for k in sorted(self._bid_ladder, reverse=True)]
            for key in keys:
                bids.append((key, *self._bid_orders[key]))
            return bids
        elif n == 1:
            # return best bid
            return self._bid_orders[str(max(self._bid_ladder))]
        elif n > 1:
            #return nlargest
            return self._bid_orders[str(nlargest(n, self._bid_ladder))]

    def asks(self, n=None):
        """
        Returns n asks, returning best first; default returns all.
        """
        if n is None:
            asks = []
            keys = [str(k) for k in sorted(self._ask_ladder)]
            for key in keys:
                asks.append((key, *self._ask_orders[key]))
            return asks
        elif n == 1:
            # return best bid
            return self._ask_orders[str(min(self._ask_ladder))]
        elif n > 1:
            #return nsmallest
            return self._ask_orders[nsmallest(n, self._ask_ladder)]

    def remove_bid(self, order):
        """
        Removes bid order if it exists in our ledger
        :param order:
        :return: True if it was removed, False if it didn't exist
        """
        try:
            return self._remove(order, self._bid_orders, self._bid_ladder)
        except OrderRemovalError as e:
            log.error(e)

    def remove_ask(self, order):
        """
        Removes ask order if it exists in our ledger
        :param order:
        :return: True if it was removed, False if it didn't exist
        """
        try:
            return self._remove(order, self._ask_orders, self._ask_ladder)
        except OrderRemovalError as e:
            log.error(e)



    def add_bid(self, order):
        return self._add(order, self._bid_orders, self._bid_ladder)

    def add_ask(self, order):
        return self._add(order, self._ask_orders, self._ask_ladder)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = Ledger()

    l.add_ask((500, 5.5, 5))
    l.add_ask((501, 1.0, 4))
    l.add_ask((502, 5.4, 70))

    l.add_bid((500, 5.5, 5))
    l.add_bid((501, 1.0, 4))
    l.add_bid((502, 5.4, 70))

    print(l.asks())
    print(l.bids())

    # Test updating
    print("Testing update..")
    l.add_bid((502, 5.4, 10))
    l.add_ask((502, 5.4, 10))
    print(l.asks())
    print(l.bids())

    # Test removing
    print("Testing removing..")
    l.remove_bid((501, 6, 0))
    l.remove_ask((501, 6, 0))
    print(l.asks())
    print(l.bids())

    print("Testing update..")
```

The main concern is performance - I will be making thousands of calls to this class, so I'd like to make the adding, removing and querying as fast as possible.

Some implementations I've already considered:

1. Using the `itemgetter` from the `operator` module in combination with `dict()`s only, eliminating the need for `set()`s.

I didn't like this, because I had to check the entire dict by calling the index of each key (if I stored orders like so: `{'price': [price, amount, count]}`). Keeping a set of dict keys seemed simpler and faster.

2. Using `dict().keys()` as substitute for `set()`

I did consider this, but wasn't sure on how well this would perform, given the frequent calls it would receive. Could someone elaborate on how much better this would perform ? The most obvious advantage would be that it only calls on a single object (`dict()`) instead of two (`dict()` and `set()`). The disadvantage appears to be to have to call `dict.keys()` every time I want to return values from it (since I need to sort them first) - instead of just sorting the `set()`.

3. Using `namedtuple` instead of `dict()`

I considered this at first, but since they're immutable, creating a new `namedtuple` instance on every update seemed redundant and wasteful.

Those were my considerations. Please do feel free to correct any of these assumptions - I've been coding for just under a year professionally, so my experience is limited. Also, pointers where I can improve my code style are welcome as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people like to keep their code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) rather than WET, I would recomend that you [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).
If we look at [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), you'll see:

> Simple is better than complex.

What I'm trying to say is your code is hard to read, and you should definitely not start optimising from this base.
As building on a base of sand is always going to lead to structural imperfections.
And then one day it'll fail, and you'll need to start afresh.

So lets first look at how you can improve your base.

---

- `bids` and `asks` change three things, and so you could merge these.
- `bid` and `ask` have the same interface. Make a class for it.
- `self._bid_ladder` is the equivalent of `self._bin_orders.keys()`.
- Both `_add` and `_remove` can be changed to be a couple of lines long by removing the 'ladders'.
- `bid` and `ask` would make more sense if you allowed the new class to have the `__getitem__` special method.

And so honestly I'd entirely re-write this.
Without `__getitem__` you should be able to get to the following on your own:

```
class Orders:
    def __init__(self, reverse=False):
        self._orders = {}
        self._reverse = reverse

    def add(self, order):
        self._orders[order[0]] = order
        return True

    def remove(self, price):
        try:
            self._orders.pop(price)
            return True
        except KeyError:
            return False

class Ledger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ask = Orders()
        self.bid = Orders(True)
```

However as `__getitem__` can take both an `int` and a `slice`, you'll have to take that into account.
You don't need `heapq` and your usage of it was *completely broken* as you get a list back not an item.
You can do everything with `sorted` and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).
And makes things simpler.

You want to:

1. Sort the orders' dictionary.
2. If is instance of `int`:

   1. Perform an `islice` of one item.
   2. Return the dict's item.
3. If the key isn't an instance of `slice`:

   1. Raise `TypeError`.
4. Otherwise perform an `islice` of the slices start, stop and step.
5. Return the sliced orders.

Or in Python:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    keys = sorted(self._orders.keys(), reverse=self._reverse)
    if isinstance(key, int):
        key, = islice(keys, key, key + 1)
        return self._orders[key]
    elif not isinstance(key, slice):
        raise TypeError()
    return [
        self._orders[key]
        for key in islice(keys, key.start, key.stop, key.step)
    ]
```

Now that you've got a simpler base you can start improving performance.
If I were to want to improve the performance I'd change the dict that we use to a self made 'SortedDict'. Python already has an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects), and you can adapt [the source-code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/collections/__init__.py) for your needs.
This is as the only performance sink is the `sorted` in `__getitem__`.

But honestly I don't know if it's worth it.

Comment: Yea, I tend to not think about simplicity when I start, and so I always try to apply dry afterwards, which leaves me with code like this. Thanks for the pointers!